# Creating a program

Tags: windows, lan

I want to create a program (in Windows machine) which will display me a window where i can add/remove entries (with 3-4 characteristics such as name , object , time remaining etc.)

After that I want to make the time count backwards from 3:40h and when 0 is reached display a new high priority alert window to alert me about the name and object characteristics with 2 options( ok (delete entry) , postpone(5 min.))

All that, I want them to be accessible by 3 PCs in same Lan Network and having the alert pop up in every PC when time reaches 0 and the changes to be real time (or with small delay) when adding or removing entries. I don't care about long term saving. Just as long as the computer which works as "server" is on. If it restarts I don't mind the program to start from scratch with empty entries in both "server" and "clients".

All I ask is what programming language can meet my requirements (especially the connection part).

I know one option is to create it as a webpage using wampp server but I would prefer something that works out of a browser.

Comment: `"what programing language can meet my requirements"` - Just about any.

Comment: I know that. But what would you use for something like that. What is easier for making this thing work. Just a suggestion

Comment: Probably an HTML/JS running on a local web server is the easiest route for you

Comment: @JimNoulis: I would use C#.  Mostly because that's where I have the bulk of my experience.

Comment: Thank you both. I think i ll give a try with C# and if things go south i ll go with the local web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just in your boat like 6 months ago.  I started out with scriptcase which is a php/ide (it is a program that helps you write php applications you can put on a web server)... but that is kinda costly.. around 400 bucks are so.  Then I found out about Visual Studio.  You can get that free from Microsoft [Download here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/).  VS has tons of samples and examples for you to create anything.
The programming language to use is called c# (C sharp) and with VS you can make a basic windows "form" which is a standard "window" in windows.

If this answers your question be sure to press the checkmark.  Thanks